# How to take the average from one worksheet with variable number of rows and get it onto another?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to take the average of a column of data that has a variable number of rows from one sheet, and then paste that average onto another sheet within the same workbook. Any suggestions?

To add, I want to take the average of a variable number of rows with 33 different columns from one worksheet and put the average from each of those columns into one cell of another worksheet (C3 through C35).

For reference, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQUQ8.png) is the sheet that has 33 other columns of data like these. the number of rows is variable depending on how long the data was collected. I want to take the average of one column, and display that average in the corresponding cell like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbXlH.png). I have 33 columns, so that would give me 33 different averages to go into this other sheet.

Comment: You need to clarify; which columns you want to get the average, and the cell range in the second workbook to place the average for each column.

Comment: What column does your data start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider passing the entire range of values in the column into a dynamic array, and then use the average worksheet function.

For example:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Variant

    Worksheets(1).Select
    x = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
 'assuming your values are in column A and the first cell is A1, and that there are no blank rows

    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(x)
'assuming you want to paste the average value on cell A1 of the second worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfect, now, if I wanted to do that for multiple columns, how would I do that?

Comment: How many columns are there? And are these columns continuous like side by side, or is it a noncontiguous range that you want to average?

Comment: 33 Columns, no blank cells

Comment: In that case, since they are all side by side with no blank cells between the columns, you should be able to use `x = Range("A1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))` (assuming you're average from column A to column C) to select the entire range of cells for the data you want to average.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dynamic ranges with the OFFSET function.
You'll have to create one dynamic range per column you want to average.

Go to Formulas tab -> Defined Ranges -> Name Manager -> New

In "Name:" add a name to you dynamic range to be used in other formulas. This name can be used in any sheet. In my example, I used RngToAverage`. Other ranges should have other names.

In "Refers to:" `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;0;COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A);1)`

[image: Name the Range]
[image: OFFSET function]

[image: Result]

My example function will work only for column A, and the reference is the cell A1.

Reference for OFFSET use: https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-offset

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic loop to insert the average of each column from the data worksheet into the second worksheet in Column C.  You will need to change the worksheet names as needed. It assumes that the data in the first worksheet starts at Column B and Row 2. Comments are provided within the code. If you have any questions, please ask.

```
 'Define the worksheet variables
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change "Sheet1" to the name of the sheet with data
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change "Sheet1" to the name of the sheet to put the averages

'This code assums that '"Compressor Discharge Press." is in Column B of the first worksheet and data starts on row 2 (clarify if the column and row are different)
'Loop through column C in the second worksheet, startting at row 2, and inserts the average for the corresponding column(with variable row counts) in the first worksheet

    For x = 2 To 34
        ws2.Cells(x, "C").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, x), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp)))
    Next x
```